# Initial (Undefined index) error, that disappears later, why?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I am trying to get a date range input through html form and output results corresponding to the input dates through PDO method. When i run the script, i am getting the below error msg. Although when i try to input dates and press submit, the error msg disappears and i am successfully getting my desired results.

> 1. **Undefined index: from_date**
> 2. **Undefined index: to_date**

Why am i getting this initial error msg which disappears later? Please advise! i am a beginner.

```
<?php
require_once 'db_alternate2.php';
session_start(); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$fromDate = $_POST['from_date'];    
$toDate = $_POST['to_date'];        

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_db` WHERE `stu_registered_date` BETWEEN   
'$fromDate' AND '$toDate'"; 


$q = $conn->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

my HTML form input

```
    <form action="student_sort.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-left">
      <p>From date</p> <input type="date" name="from_date" placeholder="From date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-right">
       <p>To date</p> <input type="date" name="to_date" placeholder="To date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-centre">
       <input class="submit" type="submit" value="search"/>         
    </div>      
    </form>
```

and my PHP output in the same page is

```
   <tbody><?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['stu_call_received']); ?></td>  
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['stu_counselled_by']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['stu_due_date']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: I think this whole code is on one page?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh: Yes. all in one page. What do you think the problem might be? I am forcing my program not to show the error by giving `error_reporting(0);`. But i wish to know where i am going wrong that leads this error. Please advise.

Comment: First put html then lower php code and then at last first one. Best practic is to do on different page.Also change it $fromDate = (isset($_POST['from_date']) && !empty($_POST['from_date']))?$_POST['from_date'] : '' ;    and same for other one. And your file extension will be .php.

Comment: great. atleast vote up my comment.if possible.

Comment: I guess we can't vote up comments we post as comments here! If only we post it as answer, we will be able to vote up! Please correct me if i am wrong! Thanks again!

Comment: just go to my comment you get a flag signature. i hope you can click on that

Comment: @anantkumarsingh: :( i am sorry i am not getting any flag signature here near to your comment.. But i am truly grateful to your help!

Comment: hey it's cool, no props